# How do I load a model through AssimpNet into Monogame?

Tags: models, monogame, assimp

I am new to MonoGame and to 3d and I'm stuck on how to import a model. It seems the best way to import a mesh model and 3d animations in Monogame in Windows 8 is through AssimpNet. I can't find a basic-level tutorial on this.

I am looking for code to import in a format Blender supports (DAE, OBJ, 3DS), view the imported mesh and perform something basic like a camera rotation around it.

Is there a way to load data imported through AssimpNet into the Model object in Monogame?

Comment: "From what I can see the best way to import a mesh model and 3d animations in Monogame in Windows 8 is through AssimpNet." What led you to that conclusion? I belive the normal thing to do is use the XNA content compiler.

Comment: Well, I've tried adding FBX and OBJ files using Content.Load<Model> and get the "Could not load asset as non-content file" exception in Xna.Framework.Content

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant the Pipeline. I'll check out the compiler thanks.

Comment: "The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.ContentPipeline.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk." I get this error since I don't have XNA installed. I can't install XNA since I'm on Windows 8

Comment: "I can't install XNA since I'm on Windows 8" Yes you can. https://msxna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20install%20XNA%204.0%20on%20Visual%20Studio%202013&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: ContentCompiler only shows filetypes for Textures, Audio and Fonts. I do see a reference to FBXImporter and XImporter in the PipelineAssemblies string but nothing in the program. Also, is there support for 3DS or OBJ?

Comment: I've used https://github.com/tgjones/osiris which has additional 3rd party processors for .obj. and .3ds with few issues.

Comment: I am currently using VC# 2010 Express as the IDE. Could this be an issue as on some sites I see them say that it wont cut the mustard and I need VS2012 at least?

Comment: You can install a newer VS and simply use it only for compilation of assets. No need to change your dev enviorment. Unless things have change shince I activly developed using MonoGame this is the easiest way to handle assets.

Comment: Would still be good to get an answer to the OP's question.  AssimpNet looks very good but is lacking documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took a look through the MonoGame content pipeline code to see how it works and turns out its using AssImpNET. So importing your models via the MonoGame pipeline is a solution to your question.

Just from reading the AssImp documentation it looks like this code could handle formats other than ".fbx", ".x" dictated by the annotation. Issues would arise if different file structures would alter how the _scene is laid out which would require you to transform the scene so that it lines up with what MonoGame requires.

```
    [ContentImporter(".fbx", ".x", DisplayName = "Open Asset Import Library - MonoGame", DefaultProcessor = "ModelProcessor")]
```

**[MonoGame:OpenAssetImporter.cs](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/4cf801e6003c272265d6cd138441f9c9ebb3eb45/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline/OpenAssetImporter.cs)**

```
    public override NodeContent Import(string filename, ContentImporterContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ContentIdentity(filename, string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImporterName) ? GetType().Name : ImporterName);

        using (var importer = new AssimpContext())
        {
            _scene = importer.ImportFile(filename,
                //PostProcessSteps.FindInstances | // No effect + slow?
                PostProcessSteps.FindInvalidData |
                PostProcessSteps.FlipUVs |
                PostProcessSteps.FlipWindingOrder |
                //PostProcessSteps.MakeLeftHanded | // Appears to just mess things up
                PostProcessSteps.JoinIdenticalVertices |
                PostProcessSteps.ImproveCacheLocality |
                PostProcessSteps.OptimizeMeshes |
                //PostProcessSteps.OptimizeGraph | // Will eliminate helper nodes
                PostProcessSteps.RemoveRedundantMaterials |
                PostProcessSteps.Triangulate
                );

            _globalInverseXform = _scene.RootNode.Transform;
            _globalInverseXform.Inverse();

            _rootNode = new NodeContent
            {
                Name = _scene.RootNode.Name,
                Identity = identity,
                Transform = ToXna(_scene.RootNode.Transform)
            };

            _materials = ImportMaterials(identity, _scene);

            FindMeshes(_scene.RootNode, _scene.RootNode.Transform);

            if (_scene.HasAnimations)
            {
                var skeleton = CreateSkeleton();
                CreateAnimation(skeleton);
            }

            // If we have a simple hierarchy with no bones and just the one
            // mesh, we can flatten it out so the mesh is the root node.
            if (_rootNode.Children.Count == 1 && _rootNode.Children[0] is MeshContent)
            {
                var absXform = _rootNode.Children[0].AbsoluteTransform;
                _rootNode = _rootNode.Children[0];
                _rootNode.Identity = identity;
                _rootNode.Transform = absXform;
            }

            _scene.Clear();
        }

        return _rootNode;
    }
```